# Show only one element from an array

Tags: knockout.js

I am having an observableArray() and I show all elements in a list with a foreach binding. 
Now I want to show only one of the elements next to the list with some detailed information about the element when someone clicks it in the list. How do I do such a thing?
Maybe I am making some bad search but I can´t find any answers on Google.

Best regards,
Martin

Answer (score 1):

Introduce a new observable for the selected item:

```
self.selectedItem = ko.observable();
```

Then add a [click binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html) within your list:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li data-bind="click: $root.selectedItem, value: text"></li>
</ul>
```

Then your detailed info could look something like this:

```
<div data-bind="visible: selectedItem, if: selectedItem">
    <h2 data-bind="text: selectedItem().text"></h2>
</div>
```

Comment: A big "Thank you!" is coming your way. This is exacly what I wanted :-)